# How can i use lists to create a story sequence?

Tags: list, function, conditional-statements, lisp, racket

I am participating in a project,which very important for me to complete.Its more of a story game,where the choices you make will determine how the story will unfold and end.I have decided to use lists to make these choices.I am responsible for creating the first choice.The first choice has to options A and B.if choice A is selected ;`A. Confidently stepped right in to solve the mystery atop Skelen Manor.`it should use list append as follows

```
(define (opening choice)
  

(cond
  [(list? A) (append (list line1 choice ))]
  [(list?  b) (append (list line2 line3))]))
```

but i have noticed that the list? function just checks whether a given list exists or not.when i run the functions this is the output

```
(opening b)
'(("Walking away from the police chatter, I approached the eery-looking Skelen Manor, a relic of an\n;older generation; and as I opened the golden doors into the manor, I took a deep breath and")
  ("Ran away due to my fear of death and the boredom of the paperwork after the matter"))
```

when i run this expression `(append (list line2 line3))` it produces the correct result

```
(("You have failed the case, and let down the department... but worry not! Would you\n;like to try again?")
  ("press no the game will CLOSE\nor  press Yes the game will restart from the Chapter 1 intro text as typed above"))
```

how can i modify my function so it produces the same result using conditions

line1 is a list which is defined as `(define A '("Confidently stepped right in to solve the mystery atop Skelen Manor."))`

here is my entire code

```
(define A '("Confidently stepped right in to solve the mystery atop Skelen Manor."))
(define b '( "Ran away due to my fear of death and the boredom of the paperwork after the matter"))
(define line1 '("Walking away from the police chatter, I approached the eery-looking Skelen Manor, a relic of an
;older generation; and as I opened the golden doors into the manor, I took a deep breath and"))
(define line2 '("You have failed the case, and let down the department... but worry not! Would you
;like to try again?"))
(define line3 '( "press no the game will CLOSE
or  press Yes the game will restart from the Chapter 1 intro text as typed above"))

(define r '("dhdhdhh2"))

;intro text  "The wind howls, the raven's shriek, the fog blows--something is"


;Walking away from the police chatter, I approached the eery-looking Skelen Manor, a relic of an
;older generation; and as I opened the golden doors into the manor, I took a deep breath and...


 



(define (opening choice)
  

(cond
  [(list? A) (append (list line1 choice ))]
  [(list?  b) (append (list line2 line3))]))




    (define line1 '("Walking away from the police chatter, I approached the eery-looking Skelen Manor, a relic of an
    ;older generation; and as I opened the golden doors into the manor, I took a deep breath and"))

however,i would like to use a function which can check WHICH list has been selected and then take appropriate action.For example if List A is chosen then it will countiue the game,but if list b,then it should run the list for the error - 

    (define line2 '("You have failed the case, and let down the department... but worry not! Would you
    ;like to try again?"))
```

Comment: It looks like you're guessing a lot. Start your interpreter, enter `(define a (list "hi")) (define b (list "there"))`, then compare `a`, `'a`, `(list a b)`, `(append a b)`, and `(append a)`
. (Scheme probably has the best selection of free [good](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) [books](http://htdp.org) of any language.)

Comment: If the opening depends on the value of `choice`, shouldn't the condition (rather than the result) include `choice`?

Comment: Also, Racket's documentation is excellent, far better than you'll find in most multimillion dollar commercial software.